# How to fix broken gcc compiler in conda

Tags: gcc, cmake, anaconda, conda, gnu

I am trying to compile some software that contains a compile.sh shell script. When I run the script, the software fails to compile due to what it reports as a broken C compiler.

I have tried reinstalling C compilers, both within and outside of conda, to no avail.

Below, please find the output of running the compile shell script

```
(base) userA@server:~/SPAdes-3.13.0-dev$ ./spades_compile.sh
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/userA/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/userA/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -- broken
CMake Error at /home/userA/anaconda3/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/home/userA/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/userA/SPAdes-3.13.0-dev/build_spades/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_708f4/fast
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_708f4.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_708f4.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/userA/SPAdes-3.13.0-dev/build_spades/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_708f4.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /home/userA/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc   -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_708f4.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/userA/SPAdes-3.13.0-dev/build_spades/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_708f4
    /home/userA/anaconda3/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_708f4.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /home/userA/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe   -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_708f4.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_708f4
    /home/userA/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
    /home/userA/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgcc
    /home/userA/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgcc
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_708f4.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'cmTC_708f4' failed
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_708f4] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/userA/SPAdes-3.13.0-dev/build_spades/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Makefile:121: recipe for target 'cmTC_708f4/fast' failed
    make: *** [cmTC_708f4/fast] Error 2




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

Expected result: properly compiled software

Actual result: report of a broken C compiler

Comment: I realize this doesn't solve the issue, but why not just use [the Bioconda build of SPAdes](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/spades)? I.e., `conda install -c bioconda spades`

Comment: @merv I am trying to use a tool (biosynthetic SPAdes) that is not available in the current release of SPAdes. It is only available as dev code, that needs to be compiled.